# c++ passing a dynamic array to a

Tags: c++

I have this piece of code and I am trying to pass the dynamically allocated array spiel to the Guess function but I get the following error from g++

```
 error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'Player&' from expression of type
'Players*'
 Guess(*spiel, spiel->player);
```

I thought that since `new` returns a pointer, I should not dereference the array?? Please help me figure out the error of my ways.

```
struct Game;
struct Player;

void startGame(Game *game);
void Guess(Game &game, Player & player);
bool HasPlayers(Game &game);
void PlayerStats(Game &game);
void DestroyGame(Game *game);

struct Players{
   string name;
   int hits;
   int misses;
   int guesses;
   char playing;
  };


struct Game{
    int running;
    char level;
    int numPlayers;
    Players *player;
```

};

```
int main()
{
    Game *spiel = new struct Game();
    spiel->player = new Players[spiel->numPlayers];

    cout << "\nWelcome to Spiel v0.4\n\n";

    startGame(spiel);
    Guess(*spiel, spiel->player);    <===== this line produces the error
    HasPlayers(*spiel);
    PlayerStats(*spiel);
    DestroyGame(spiel);
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I edited it

Comment: The second argument for Guess is a reference to `Player`, Hence you should pass the object i.e. as `Guess(*speil, *(speil->player))`

Comment: @UchiaItachi thank you so much. The program compiled. So thats at least one obstacle out of the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @billz mentioned there is a typo change `Player` to `Players` in Guess function

And importantly you're `Guess` function accepts a reference to `Players`

So, you should call like `Guess(*speil,*(speil->player))`.

And, also `numPlayers` is **uninitialized** this can be dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

Your forward declaration type is `Player`, however, your concrete type is `Players`

Update:

```
struct Player;
void Guess(Game &game, Player & player);
```

to

```
struct Players;
void Guess(Game &game, Players & player);
```

Or change all `Players` to `Player` accordingly.

Also `Guess` only takes one `Player` as input but `spiel->player` is initialized with an array of players, so the type doesn't match. However, you can pass single player object in:

```
Guess(*speil, spiel->player[0]);
```

Or you could change `Guess` function signature to accept an array of `Players`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the pointer itself, you need the actual object. Instead, pass either &speil->player or *speil->player. Depending on your compiler. You also need to change your Guess() function definition (types are not spelled the same).